# How to get selected image name from gallery in xamarin android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

How to Get selected image name from gallery in xamarin android .when USer Click on button then image gallery is open and i get image but i don not know how to get the image name.

This is the button click event when user click on the button the image gallery is open and i select the image

```
fab2.Click += (o, e) =>
            {

              Intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionPick,
              MediaStore.Images.Media.InternalContentUri);
              Intent.SetType("image/*");

              StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent,"SelectPicture"), 1 );

            };
```

When image is selected i get the image but ...here is i have problem .i dont know how i get the selected image name.

```
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
      base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      if ((requestCode == PickImageId) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
      {

        Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
        string path = uri.Path;
        string filename = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);


        // String s = path(selectedImageUri);
        Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(ContentResolver, data.Data);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify This Code Add Method Getpath() and it will return you path of selected image where you can get the Name of selected image.

```
 protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
          base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
          if ((requestCode == PickImageId) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
          {
            string imagePath = null;
            Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
            var path = GetPath(uri);

            string filename = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);


            // String s = path(selectedImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.GetBitmap(ContentResolver, data.Data);
          }
        }


 public string GetPath(Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
      string path = null;
      String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.Data };
      ContentResolver cr = ApplicationContext.ContentResolver;
      var metaCursor = cr.Query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
      if (metaCursor != null)
      {
        try
        {
          if (metaCursor.MoveToFirst())
          {
            path = metaCursor.GetString(0);
          }
        }
        finally
        {
          metaCursor.Close();
        }

      }
      return path;
    }
```